# Is this one a complex sentence?

Tags: participle-clauses

This vase, made in China in the 14th century, is very valuable.

"made in China in the 14th century" is a dependent sentence.

Then, is "This vase, is very valuable." an independent sentence or dependent sentence?

Comment: I think It is a "non-restrictive relative clause".

Comment: The main clause is "This vase is very valuable". The clause "made in China in the 14th century" is a supplement, a loosely attached element providing non-integrated content.

Comment: "made in China in the 14th century" is not a sentence/ clause, but just a phrase.

Comment: @RamPillai No, it's not a phrase. It's a past participle clause, the semantic equivalent of the relative clause "which was made in China in the 14th century".